# How do I calculate the fingerprint of an asset?

Tags: token

If I have an asset with

policy id: `2697bec9e609932eaaaafb34c8e1ea706549d268166ef60285026b85`

asset name: `redomgrun`

How do I calculate the fingerprint `asset107k0vzcplp8rjc3d2y8cew6z2gdhvnqru2uluu`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [CIP14: User-Facing Asset Fingerprint](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0014/CIP-0014.md), we calculate it as:

```
assetFingerprint := encodeBech32
  ( datapart = hash
    ( algorithm = 'blake2b'
    , digest-length = 20
    , message = policyId | assetName
    )
  , humanReadablePart = 'asset'
  )
```

Or you can just use an existing library, such as [cip14-js](https://github.com/Emurgo/cip14-js) by Emurgo.

Comment: do you know of any java implementation of it?

Comment: See Satya's answer to the question, he could not reply a comment as his user is too new.

Answer (score 3):

A Java implementation will be available in [cardano-client-lib](https://github.com/bloxbean/cardano-client-lib) next release. (0.2.0)

For now, you can refer to "calculateFingerPrint" method of [this](https://github.com/bloxbean/cardano-client-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bloxbean/cardano/client/util/AssetUtil.java) class (see [here](https://github.com/bloxbean/cardano-client-lib/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bloxbean/cardano/client/util/AssetUtilTest.java) for tests).